# Google play services mobile ads requires AdMob account

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, ads, google-play

I am finally at the last step of publishing my app. The only thing I have left is to integrate ads. I want to ask a few questions about how google play services work. 1.Is an AdMob account required or I can integrate ads just with google play services mobile ads sdk? 2.If an AdMob account is required I can create one for free after I have my developer's account or do I have to pay additional taxes or wait for a confirmation? And the last question: 3.The AdMob (if necessary) account is connected to the google wallet and to the developer's account? I am totally new in this process called app monetizing. I tried to make an AdMob account and it requested and url to the app that you want to monetize, but how can it ask you for this, if you haven't published the app yet? Aren't you supposed to launch the app with ads from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["AdMob requires you to have a valid AdSense account and AdWords account"](https://apps.admob.com/admob/signup)

1. An adsense & Adwords(admob) account is required to generate ad unit IDs, link apps and receive payments
2. Creating the account is totally free. You only need a google account which is also free
3. The account won't be connected to a google wallet or developer account. You enter your payment info to receive payments via wire, paypal, western union depending on your location/country.

I don't see anywhere where you're supposed to enter the url of the app. Make sure you're using apps.admob.com. admob.com is no longer supported. With that, you can enter your app manually and link  later after you've published it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Now all the process is crystal clear.